# eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix - formula

Tags: linear-algebra

To find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of an n × n matrix A, let I be the n × n
identity matrix. Rewriting Ax = λx as λIx = Ax and rearranging gives ( λI − A ) x = 0. This homogeneous system of equations has nonzero solutions if and only if the
coefficient matrix ( λI − A ) is not invertible—that is, if and only if its determinant is zero.

Why the matrix (λI−A) is singular?

Comment: By definition, singularity means non-invertible.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for those values of $\lambda$ such that $(A-\lambda I)$ is singular, in this case you have solution different from the trivial one x=0 and thus you can find the special vectors (named eigenvectors) such that:

$$Ax=\lambda x$$

Comment: Why the matrix (A−λI) isn't invertible?

Comment: because the det is zero

Comment: thus it doesn't represent an bijective transformation and thus it is not invertible, there are many ways to explain this fact

Comment: the key point is that you are looking for $(A-\lambda I)$ not invertible in order to have non tirvial solutions

Comment: I can't understand why the homogeneous system of equations has nonzero solutions if and only if the coefficient matrix ( λI − A ) is non-invertible. 

Why if the coefficient matrix ( λI − A ) is invertible the homogeneous system has only trivial solutions?

Comment: If a square matrix is invertible Ax=0 has only one solution that is x=0, otherwise you can have multiple solution. I suggest to clarify this point first to study eigenvalues and eigenvectors, it's a basic fact for matrices. Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: I solved my doubt! Thank you.

Comment: @Walter You are welcome, if you are ok you can accept the answer and set as solved, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

excuse my english please

As you know that the main goal is to find solution of the following algebraic equation $$Ax=b$$
so we begin by searching the values of  $ \lambda $  verify  $ Ax=\lambda x  $  for some $ \lambda $ we can find some vectors, verify that equality, wich will be called eigenspace generated by the eigenvalue $ \lambda $, and lets assume that the direct sum of that eigenspaces cover the whole space, so every $ x $ can be written as $ x=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i $ such that $ x_i $ correspond to the eigenvalue $ \lambda_i $ then we have $$Ax=A \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i= \sum_{i=1}^{n}Ax_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i x_i    $$ finly to find the solution of $Ax=b$ we have only to compare the coefficient of $ b=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i x_i  $ with such of $Ax= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_i x_i    $

At the end you can  see that if the nullspace of $(\lambda I -A)$ is $\{0\}$ with mean that $ (\lambda I -A) $have no  singularities  and $ Ax=\lambda x $ have only $ x=0 $ as solution  so this case will be useless

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the basic definition: $v\ne0$ is an eigenvector of $A$ if there is a scalar $\lambda$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. So, once you know that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, you’re looking for non-zero solutions to the equation $Av=\lambda v$, which you can rewrite as $(\lambda I-A)v=0$. Such non-zero solutions exist iff the null space of $\lambda I-A$ is nontrivial, which is equivalent to the matrix being singular.